# Understanding Coordinate systems, rotation and translation in both Project Tango and PCL

Tags: android, 3d, rotation, point-cloud-library, google-project-tango

I'm using Project Tango to get the depth data and then I send the 3d point cloud to a native class to process the data using pcl library. I have couple of questions, which I think they will help me understanding more about rotation, translation, and coordinate systems in both pcl and tango. Also, they will help me solving my problem in the project I'm working on.

1. I'm working in an obstacle detection system which should work in real-time, and I'm using the default coordinate system in Tango? is this right? shouldn't I use the area description coordinate frame?
2. In my current scenario, I'm taking the 3D cloud data which is in the camera frame of reference and process them without changing the frame of reference. I have three related question here:

   - Is it alright to work directly on the data while it in the camera frame?
   - Since I use PCL for processing, what is the coordinate system in pcl are the x point to the right, y point to the bottom, and z forward from the camera as in the camera coordinate system of Tango?
   - Is transforming the cloud to the start of device is transforming to the origin (world frame)?
3. In the scenario in my project users should hold the device in a X rotated degree around the x axis, I have read from other posted questions that the pitch/roll/yaw are not the reliable way to get the rotation of the device and I have to use the pose data provided by tango, is it correct? how can I determine the right rotation angle of the device so that I can rotate the cloud to make sure that the surface normal of the floor will be parallel to the Y axis? (Please have a look to the pictures to have an idea of what I mean)

[image: the way users should hold the device]

[image: The way I imagin my coordinate direction look Like]

[image: The coordinate direction that I would like to reach to detect floor]

4. How Can I use the pose data to traslate and rotate the cloud data in pcl?

**note:**

I have a related quetion to this one, which shows the results of my 3d point cloud processing code and its output: 
[Related Question: how to detect the floor palne?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093408/google-project-tango-how-to-detect-if-the-plane-is-a-floor-from-3d-point-cloud)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I will post some answers to my questions.

1 and 2.1 - To get better results regarding floor plane normal angle, the best coordinate work for me is OpenGL world coordinate.

2.2- please refer to the answer in this link: [answer link (pcl forum)](http://www.pcl-users.org/What-is-the-coordinate-system-orientation-in-pcl-td4043150.html)

3. For the rotation and translation, I used the pose data from Tango device, I have read that they are better than getting the rotation of the device itself. 
   Thus, I get the the pose data at the same time as the point cloud and then I send them to the native code and perform the translation using PCL library.

Hope this will be helpful for someone.